# How to make bootstrap columns scrollable?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to make this card x-scrollable. But after three blocks, the fourth block is rendering in the new line.
I want to scroll horizontally. I tried everything from past 5 days.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper d-flex">
        <div class="p-4 pt-5" id='content' style="width:100%">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <h2><strong>Please make this scrollable horizonally</strong></h2>
                    <div class="card card-section">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Heading
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form method="post">
                                <div class='container-fluid'>
                                    <div class='row customClass'>
                                        <div class='col-md-4'>
                                                <div style='width:300px;background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-md-4'>
                                            <div style='width:300px;background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-md-4'>
                                            <div style='width:300px;background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-md-4'>
                                            <div style='width:300px;background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.customClass {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.customClass .col-md-4 {
  display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/maharshi9999/pen/qBddebG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the row class. Use what you have just remove that class as boom done!

`<div class='customClass'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>`

if want something different to your approach, let me know. 
Good luck!

Comment: It works now but the display is extending right side. Actually it is a code part in django project. I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: change this ->   
`<div class='container-fluid'>
 <div class='customClass'>`
to ->
`<div class='container'>
 <div class='customClass'>`
fluid will make it... fluid, which means will change its size to the contents. 
I hope this fixes it :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 uses flex. In case if you want override the wrapping sytle of Bootstrap row you have to use flex-wrap:nowrap; for row.
https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/Exjjqzx

```css
.row.customClass {
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
 <title></title>
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper d-flex">
  <div class="p-4 pt-5" id='content' style="width:100%">
   <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="container-fluid">
     <h2><strong>Please make this scrollable horizonally</strong></h2>
     <div class="card card-section">
      <div class="card-header">
       Heading
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
       <form method="post">
        <div class='container-fluid'>
         <div class='row customClass'>
          <div class='col-md-4'>
            <div style='width:300px;background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-4'>
           <div style='width:300px;background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-4'>
           <div style='width:300px;background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-4'>
           <div style='width:300px;background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed `col-md-4` classes as well as set the width to `customClass`.

```css
.card-body {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.customClass {
  width: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
 <title></title>
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper d-flex">
  <div class="p-4 pt-5" id='content' style="width:100%">
   <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="container-fluid">
     <h2><strong>Please make this scrollable horizonally</strong></h2>
     <div class="card card-section">
      <div class="card-header">
       Heading
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
       <form method="post">
        <div class='container-fluid'>
         <div class='row customClass'>
          <div class='col'>
            <div style='background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
          </div>
          <div class='col'>
           <div style='background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
          </div>
          <div class='col'>
           <div style='background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
          </div>
          <di class='col'>
           <div style='background-color:green;height: 500px; margin: 10px;'></div>
          </di>
         </div>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
 </script>-->
</body>
</html>
```